# HTML Form Not Sending file input

Tags: html

I have a form that sends along some standard input, but then freaks out at the file and just doesn't even say it's there.  What could be going on here?  I have the enctype set correctly, so any help is welcome.

I don't get an error message.  I have my PHP to spit out the POST data so I can see what I'm getting, and I don't see the file post data.

Comment: can you show your code so that any1 can help you....?

Comment: What code do you have so far and why have you never accepted the answer to any of your questions?

Comment: Dear friend, You should ask the question with details, like your code, error message, resources you used etc.

Answer (score 1):

And it seems that I found the answer to my question.  It appears that in my PHP code, I was looking for the file in the POST superglobal, but I should have been looking at $_FILES.